Model Evaluation Strategies for Wind Energy Prediction Using Forecast Wind Speed
I am working on a regression problem to predict the amount of wind energy generated at a specific location based on hourly data. The dataset comprises four years of observations, with one row per hour, totaling 24 rows per day. The response variable is the "electricity generated" at each particular time, and the sole predictor is the wind speed forecasted for that exact time, produced the previous day by a Numerical Weather Prediction (NWP) system.
It's important to note that the model does not utilize any lagged variables; it exclusively uses the wind speed forecasted at each hour to predict the electricity generated at that same hour. The primary objective is to establish a direct relationship between the forecasted wind speed (input) and the electricity generated (output) at any time.
Given this setup, I am contemplating several strategies for model evaluation:

Training on the first three years, testing on the fourth
Time-Series Cross-Validation: Implementing a time-series cross-validation strategy, similar to the method provided by scikit-learn (details here ). This would involve a sliding time-window for training and testing the model incrementally.
Allocating the first three weeks of every month to the training set and the fourth week of every month to the testing set. This procedure results in one comprehensive training set and one final testing set. Consequently, this means the model is trained a single time on the entirety of the training set and subsequently evaluated just once on the complete testing set.

While I recognize that options 1 and 2 are correct, with the second being very time-intensive, I wonder about the correctness of option 3, given that the model doesn't incorporate past response values or any lagged predictors. Although the data has a temporal order, does the non-autoregressive nature of the model make option 3 appropriate for model evaluation?
Any insights or experiences with similar evaluation strategies would be greatly appreciated.
Update to the question:
I am particularly interested in determining if there are any statistical flaws in strategy 3. For example, I understand that randomly sampling data to create training and test sets is statistically incorrect due to the temporal order of the data, its non-i.i.d. nature, and the presence of auto-correlations. Random sampling doesn't preserve the inherent sequence, which is why time-series cross-validation — that maintains the order of data — is usually recommended in such cases (as in strategy 2). However, strategy 3 also preserves temporal order by utilizing a specific temporal block for testing (the fourth week of every month).
To illustrate, let's assume the operational application of my model is as follows: the model is trained with data up to the present and is used to predict each hour of every day for the upcoming week (this scenario is somewhat complex, but I'm using it for the sake of the argument). In this case, the most appropriate way to evaluate my model (to estimate future performance) would be using strategy 2, which simulates its future operational use.
But as I said, I’m interested in strategy 3. So, my questions would be:

Is there anything fundamentally statistically incorrect with it?
Could it serve as a reasonable approximation to strategy 2, with the advantage of being less computationally intensive? (assuming that there is nothing special about the fourth week of each month)

Update 2:
By the way, the setup of my question is very similar to that of GEFCOM2014, where in the context of wind energy forecasting, you are asked to use past data to predict generated energy for every hour of every day of the next month.
GEFCOM2014 WIND

It is hard to judge all the complexities of the problem from this short description, but my first try would be linear regression between the predicted wind speed and the electricity generated. The error comes from the actual wind speed bot being the one predicted. A scatterplot could be a good start to get better idea.

I think you should ask yourself how the model will be used in the future. Then imagine the future is already now and you did not record part of your data. This data can then be used for a hypothetical application of your model in an artificial future. For this reason I have some doubts about 3. Your model will probably not be used to forecast the prices in the fourth week of every month.

If by 1 you mean a single forecast over horizons between 1 hour ahead and 1 year ahead, this does not make sense, because in a real situation, you would not have wind speed forecasts for this horizon (beyond "climatological" ones). I would recommend you first understand which forecast horizon is relevant to you, hope that you do have wind speed forecasts over this horizon. then run a rolling origin holdout test as in method 2. Yes, this may well be time intensive. You could shorten the time here by only sampling a subset of data points. Or by updating the model instead of full refitting.

@picky_porpoise, good point, thanks! In principle, given that wind speed is forecasted everyday for each of the 24 hours of the next day, the model could be used everyday to predict how much electricity is estimated to be generated for each of the 24 hours of the next day. But, it could also be used to predict any future time period (1 week in my question update), as far as meteorological wind speed forecasts are provided every day. I understand that strategy 2 would be most appropriate for model evaluation. However, I’m mostly interested to know whether strategy 3 is fundamentally flawed.

@StephanKolassa the forecasting horizon would be 24 hours: everyday wind speed is forecasted for each of next day’s 24 hours. Still, and following strategy 1, the same model “energy=f(forecasted wind speed)” can be applied to each of the days of the fourth year, provided that wind speed forecasts are generated for every day of the fourth year. Yet, I agree that probably strategy 2 would be the best option (running origin holdout tests, as you mention). However, I’m mostly interested to know if there is something very wrong with strategy 3 …

OK, a 24 hour horizon does sound like you want some kind of rolling origin setup. No need to forecast a full year out if all you need is a day. Re option 3, I would still do rolling origin if you don't need a full week horizon. Do you mean you only model on three weeks each time, rather than the full history? That might work, but of course you will get quite different models each time, because you are not modeling the yearly seasonality any more (which you could do if you modeled on multiple years of data). But I don't see any fundamental issues with this approach.
